# How to create a new page layout in Laravel/Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This is a complete new application using Laravel 9 and Livewire

By default you have two layouts, guest and app. I want to create a new layout for all my admin things.

So, first I create a component

```
php artisan make:component AdminLayout
```

This creates `\app\View\Components\AdminLayout.php`, it read as:

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class AdminLayout extends Component {
  public function render() { return view('layouts.admin'); }
}
```

As any of the other two `AdminLayout.php` or `GuestLayout.php`

So now I write `app\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php` which is a stantandard HTML with the `{{ $slot }}` blade directive, something as...

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    ...
    @livewireStyles
    @vite([...])
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="...">
      {{ $slot }}
    </main>
    @livewireScripts
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I create the admin routes... The `Index` class is in `\app\Livewire\Admin\Index.php` and it is correctly imported

```
Route::get('', Index::class)->name('home');
```

The `Index.php` reads as

```
class Index extends Component {
  public function render() { return view('livewire.admin.index'); }
}
```

The `\app\resources\views\livewire\admin\index.blade.php` reads:

```
<x-admin-layout>
  Hello
</x-admin-layout>
```

So everything seems to be right... now I have two problems that I can't spot/solve. When I load the `http:://server.test/admin` it should load this page. 1) It doesn't change the title in the page for `Admin Page`, 2) It always loads the `@livewire('navigation-menu')`, and looks like the followin picture:

[image]

If I add things above the `{{ $slot }}` or below, they are rendered. If I add another `@livewire('navigation-menu')` it is rendered. But I'm not able to take it out, even when I'm not telling to display it.

Any idea?

I just noticed that if I add a comment in the guest layout or the admin layout, it simply ignores it. If I add a comment in the app layout it somehow "propagates" to both the guest and admin layout. Is this the expected behaivour?

Comment: Did you resolve it? @luisfer

Comment: Yes... you only had to add `->layout('whatever')` to the return view. But now I been using Livewire 3 and solves this thing much better